# string.h header in the file with the function main

Tags: c, header, string.h

I have a program with several .c and .h files.
In one of the .c files I am using the function strcmp(). I am adding in this file the header for string.h

Is the string.h header in the file with the function main also required?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, the good practice would be to include all and only the headers in the file requiring them directly.

Answer (score 3):

If the translation unit containing the function main does not use the function `strcmp` or any other declaration from the header `<string.h>` then inclusion of the header in this translation unit is redundant and only confuses readers.